# Focus next element on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

It's been a year or two since I last dabbled in jQuery and have attempted to write a simple "on key press move to the next element" script.  However my first attempt has a lot a repetition. I ***just know*** there is a more elegant way to write this, probably using a dictionary of elements or such.

---

```js
$("#DialFirst").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialSecond").focus();
    });

    $("#DialSecond").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialThird").focus();
    });

    $("#DialThird").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialFourth").focus();
    });

    $("#DialFourth").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialFifth").focus();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="DialFirst" name="DialFirst" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialSecond" name="DialSecond" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialThird" name="DialThird" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFourth" name="DialFourth" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFifth" name="DialFifth" type="text" value="" />
```

**Usage:** Type in each box, focus should move to the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input elements are all siblings of each other, so you can use [`$.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next one that appears after the event target.  There is no need to name each input individually.

```js
$(':input').keypress(function() {
    $(this).next(':input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="1">
<input placeholder="2">
<input placeholder="3">
<input placeholder="4">
<input placeholder="5">
```

Comment: Is this working in chrome? I tested and it'ss not working but working in firefox.